# Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to find all points at which a function is differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is:
Let $f(z)=(Re(z))(Im(z))(z^2+1)$. Use the Cauchy Riemann equations to find all points at which $f'(z)$ exists.

Writing the function in the form $u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$:

$f(x+iy)=(Re(z))(Im(z))(z^2+1)=xy((x+y)^2+1)=x^3y-xy^3+xy+2ix^2y^2$.

Hence $u(x,y)=x^3y-xy^3+xy$ and $v(x,y)=2x^2y^2$.

Applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, gives:

$3x^2y-y^3+y=4x^2y$ and $x^3-3xy^2+x=-4xy^2$.

Then I attempted to solve these as simultaneous equations:

$3x^2-y^2+1=4x^2$ (cancelling through first equation by $y$)

$x^2-3y^2+1=-4y^2$ (cancelling through second equation by $x$)

Simplifying:

First equation: $x^2=1-y^2$

Second equation: $y^2=-1-x^2$

Here's where my working broke down. Substituting the second equation into the first gives $x^2=1-(-1-x^2)=2+x^2$, ultimately giving $0=2$, which is clearly nonsense.

I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Assuming all the calculations are correct, you've proved it's nowhere differentiable, which certainly appears to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you overlooked the solution $(0,0)$ when you "cancelled" your $x$ and $y$. Cancelling like that is not a good idea, it is better to factor $x$ or $y$ out and consider the possibility that they be zero. Your  function is differentiable at $(0,0)$. If you set $y=0$, the first equation is satisfied and the second reduces to $x^3+x=0$ which gives you $x=0$. If you set $x=0$, the second equation is satisfied and the first one gives $y-y^3=0$ which gives you, besides $y=0$, the solutions $y=1$, $y=-1$. Your function is thus differentiable at three points.

Comment: Got it, thank you! So when solving $x^3+x=0$ for $x$, factorising gives $x(x^2+1)=0$ which gives $x=0$ or $x^2+1=0$ - do I just ignore the solution given by $x^2+1=0$, because it is not real-valued?

Comment: Yes. And in the other case you get $y(1-y^2)=0$ which has three solutions for $y$.